# Run a controller method at a fixed schedule within MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scheduled-tasks, azure-web-roles

We have an existing method in an existing controller that we'd like to call at a specific schedule (eg "daily at 2am"). The application is an MVC3 application running on Azure as a web role and we don't want to create, maintain and pay for an entire new role (worker role) just to run one small piece of identical logic.

Is it possible to schedule a controller method to trigger off at a specific scheduled time in the future? Also, would the same technique work in regular ASP.NET webforms?

Comment: Anything you can do with a worker role, you can do with a web role. So whatever your plan is for how you'd do this in a worker role, just do that in your web role instead.

Comment: smarx that's not true. Read about Phil Haack's WebBackgrounder as described http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx. per @barry . Worker role is far more robust, but if you can live with the limitations Phil outlines, you can skip the web role.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can just call this controller action with a URL, you can just...
1) create a PowerShell script to "ping" the website:
http://learn-powershell.net/2011/02/11/using-powershell-to-query-web-site-information/
2) Schedule that PowerShell script via remote desktop in a Scheduled Task that runs at 2am

You could also write a deployment script that automates #2.

Comment: Without allocating a separate VM to do that, I assume you're suggesting every web role should schedule that powershell script (configured during deployment)? We could write the controller action to respond to the 1st ping. Seems a bit hack-ish though ... maybe not on second thoughts ...

Comment: The question was without adding another role...if you look at documentation for Azure roles, one way is to have powershell scripts for startup config or install frameworks not present on the VM.  So, it's not that hackish....plus it's easy to replicate/publish multiple times and if the vm goes down, re-imaging will re run the scripts.

Comment: Yup. I guess I was looking for a more .NET framework solution (of scheduling a thread that would GET the method) than a Windows deployment + powershell solution. I guess it's tough (impossible?) since the IIS worker thread's lifespan in fairly limited.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Phil Haack's [WebBackgrounder](https://github.com/NuGet/WebBackgrounder) as described [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx).

Comment: An updated Task based solution that works in Azure would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used Cron jobs in a Shared hosting environment where scheduled tasks/powershell wasn't available.

[Here's a website](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml) explaining more about it